# Open encrypted database in Database Inspector

Tags: android, android-studio, database-inspector

How can I open the encrypted database in Android Studio's Database Inspector? It always shows the database as closed.

Comment: I face the same issue today but I guess there isn't any way to inspect the database... :)

Comment: Yeah there isn't any support yet